# Liquid that comes out raw mangoes

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

What is the composition of the liquid that comes out of a raw mango when you break it off from its stem? It oozes out some sort of juicy liquid. Any idea what that is?

Also, is it edible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the [*sap*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sap); you can see the composition of the sap (of Indian mangoes) [in this article](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0031-9422(02)00441-7). Some plants also produce [latex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latex) from injury sites. The mango sap is not supposed to be eaten as it can irritate the skin; a condition referred to as [Mango Dermatitis](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2763731/).